# Calculating divergence of vector in GLSL (or gradient of vector)

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, vector-graphics, fragment-shader

I have a situation in GLSL where I need to calculate the divergence of a vector in fragment shader

```
vec3 posVector;
```

Divergence is mathematically given by

[image]

It's a dot product between vector and Gradient.

Does anyone how to compute this ?

Comment: You can already get the screen-space partial derivative of `posVector` in GLSL with respect to X and Y using `dFdx` and `dFdy`. The with respect to Z part here makes me think that would not help you tremendously.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem here. I'm also thinking the same how to calculate dFdz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divergence of the position vector is the the divergence of the identity vector field

F: ℝ³ -> ℝ³

F(r_) = r_

and div of that is both const and known:

div(r_) = 3.